# Error code:CS2021 (File name 'C:" /debug- /optimize+ C:\svo2trpm.0.cs' is too long or invalid) While creating assembly using CODEDOM

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, codedom, system-codedom-compiler

I am trying to create an assembly using CODEDOM. The assembly am creating will contain a POCO class and the properties that this class will carry will be coming from Database. Everything is going fine , but while trying to create assembly out of the codecompliationunit, I am getting the below error.

Error code:CS2021 (File name 'C:" /debug- /optimize+  C:\svo2trpm.0.cs' is too long or invalid) While creating assembly using CODEDOM.

I am using .net framework 4.5 with Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 7. I tried to run the same code on a windows server 2016 and still the same issue.

Comment: Does this look like a valid file name to you? `C:" /debug- /optimize+ C:\svo2trpm.0.cs`? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names)

Comment: Well am not creating this file. It's created by the System.dll

Comment: Well, I fixed the issue. My bad i was passing a wrong formatted file name.